# language-check gives OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect

Tags: python, languagetool

I am trying to use language-check [a link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/language-check)

I get error on line

```
tool = language_check.LanguageTool('en-US')
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    tool = language_check.LanguageTool('en-US')
  File "C:\Users\IMI-Nidhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\language_check\__init__.py", line 196, in __init__
    self._start_server_on_free_port()
  File "C:\Users\IMI-Nidhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\language_check\__init__.py", line 333, in _start_server_on_free_port
    cls._start_local_server()
  File "C:\Users\IMI-Nidhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\language_check\__init__.py", line 357, in _start_local_server
    startupinfo=startupinfo
  File "C:\Users\IMI-Nidhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 756, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\IMI-Nidhi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1160, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

What's wrong, and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: The thing which is failing appears to be related to starting a server locally. I guess it's trying to run Java LanguageTool, presumably after having successfully downloaded it. See if you can figure out why it's failing, or if you can run it standalone.

Comment: Related ...? https://github.com/myint/language-check/issues/31